# Waking from sleep costs 7 seconds

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

When waking from sleep, my iMac takes 7+ seconds before I can load an internet page. The UI of the computer is responsive within a second. I think is not normal. When I look in the log file (via Console.app), I find some clues:

```
Oct 11 12:37:07 imac configd[13]: Sleep: Success - AC - Software Sleep
Oct 11 12:37:07 imac configd[13]: Wake: Success - AC - EHC1
Oct 11 12:37:07 imac configd[13]: Hibernate Statistics
Oct 11 12:37:07 imac configd[13]: network configuration changed.
Oct 11 12:37:07 imac configd[13]: PMConnection AirPort configd plug-in com.apple.powermanagement.applicationresponse.slowresponse 7127 ms
Oct 11 12:37:07 imac configd[13]: PMConnection IPConfiguration com.apple.powermanagement.applicationresponse.slowresponse 7128 ms
Oct 11 12:37:08 imac configd[13]: network configuration changed.
Oct 11 12:37:09 imac ntpd[12788]: sendto(194.109.22.18) (fd=24): Network is unreachable
Oct 11 12:37:18 imac ntpd[12788]: time reset +0.460758 s
Oct 11 12:37:31 imac loginwindow[29]: spins were reported for this wake
```

I turned off the AirPort (because I don't use it). So the message `PMConnection AirPort` is a bit weird. The 194.109.22.18 address is a NTP (time) server, which after waking up is available.

It's an 24" iMac, with Snow Leopard installed.

Anyone got an idea. It seems to be a networking issue...

Comment: Maybe your network card just needs a cup of coffee?

Answer (score 1):

Taking several seconds to renegotiate a wireless link when waking from sleep/hibernate is not unusual.

If you are not using wireless , then what do you mean by "have to wait 7+ seconds"? Do you get errors in that time or does your browser just take that long to show the first page you request?

Comment: The browser is reporting "You are not connected to the Internet; Gmail notifier says "Could not connect to server". After these around 7 seconds, Safari detects internet access is restored, and reloads the page...

Comment: As David said, I suppose it's the time necessary to renegociate the wireless link and get an IP address using DHCP. Maybe forcing the IP address on the Mac would speed it up?

Comment: This depends on several factors, your wireless card has to be activated, negotiate your connection, get updated DHCP information, and setup your DNS routing.  While ideally that should be instanteous, the issue arises in that different manufacturers can cause some delays during negotiation...

Comment: I don't use my WiFi connection; only my Ethernet wired LAN. Also, I forgot to mention I don't use DHCP. My computer has a fixed IP address. My 7 year old Tiger PPC iMac only takes <1 second to be operational after sleep, so my new one should at least do the same, I guess?

Comment: Has the machine been told you don't use wireless (by fully turning off any wireless adaptors it has)? Maybe it is trying to scan for wireless connections before it bothers to look at the wired one (unlikely, I know, as wired is usually the default to check first, but not impossible).

Comment: With the AirPort turned on I get the same slow response...